# Excel 2007 Pivot Tables: Overlapping issue hampers my summary sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts, pivot-table

I've created a Workbook that has 5 Pivot Tables (PT). I want to make a summary sheet that holds all these PT's, but when they expand the '**not allowed to overlap issue**' causes me updating problems - they don't update/expand effectively. Therefore, can't be printed off easily.

The sheet would basically help my users give their bosses a simple quick overview of the larger worksheet - this way they would be more inclined to fill it in (give a little too get a little philosophy).

I had thought about using the Camera Tool, but I'm not sure how you could make it dynamic, or whether it can be dynamic with a PT?

Any advice, links or step-by-steps are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the pivot tables on their own sheets and then link to the pivot table using cell references.

This will give the same view of the data, but users won't be able to pull in additional fields and cause the overlapping problem.

It may also be useful to put the PT that you are referencing on a hidden sheet and then providing a copy of the pivot table on a visible worksheet so that as the users change the view in the PT, the summary tab will not change.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert several blank rows between your PivotTables - enough to account for any possible expansion.
2. Mark empty rows as HIDDEN. If a PivotTable happens to extend into hidden rows, simply readjust which rows are hidden.
3. ???
4. Profit! (with the bosses)